# dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing, laravel composer-install with docker

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5

I clone a **PHP-Laravel docker** project. Then I up the docker container & log into it. I try to run `composer install` but it failed.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.7.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.7.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.7.0].
```

This was the error I got. Please Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I did these things also 
> `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd` & 
> enabled for *php-cli*  `sudo phpenmod gd` & 
> *php.ini* and uncomment this line `;extension=php_gd2.dll` 
but these didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded a answer.
Log into your docker container & run this command.

```
docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Using this command I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think your missing the php-gd module. That might be the reason you are getting this error. Type this below command in your terminal ,

```
php -m
```

this will give you the list of all the php modules installed. Check for the "gd" extension in it. If you don't find it then you will have to install the module. for example (I usually run it like this in my ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

This would install the latest extension of php-gd module.